# MySQL query slow in Where MONTH(datetime)

Tags: mysql, query-performance

I am trying to add index in datetime, but the result still same.

```
SELECT s.id, s.player,
COUNT(case when dg.winner = 1 AND dp.colour <= 5 then 1 when dg.winner = 2 AND dp.colour > 5 then 1 else null end) as totalwin, 
COUNT(case when dg.winner = 2 AND dp.colour <= 5 then 1 when dg.winner = 1 AND dp.colour > 5 then 1 else null end) as totallose, 
COUNT(dg.winner) as totalgames 
       FROM dotaplayers AS dp 
       LEFT JOIN gameplayers AS gp ON gp.gameid = dp.gameid and dp.colour = gp.colour 
       LEFT JOIN stats AS s ON s.player_lower = gp.name 
       LEFT JOIN dotagames AS dg ON dg.gameid = dp.gameid 
       LEFT JOIN games AS g ON g.id = dp.gameid 
       LEFT JOIN bans as b ON b.name=gp.name
       WHERE MONTH(g.datetime) = 4
       GROUP by gp.name
       ORDER BY totalwin DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

Showing rows 0 - 9 (10 total, Query took 7.7552 seconds.)

I want order the most winner in 4th month (April). Then it shows id, username, totalwins, totallose, totaldraw, totalgames. The case in my query is the how to get that. The result is correct, but slow.

Comment: Does year not matter?

Comment: @Uueerdo yeah im forget, does it will improve the performance ?

Comment: Yes, posting an answer...

Comment: improving performance without an explain plan is like driving to a destination without knowing where you are to start with.  Sure we can offer lots of insights and sooner or later we may get there, but if you want the fastest solution, we need to know why it's slow slow in the first place, or if we should head east or west to begin with or maybe north/south... Need to have an idea of where the bottle neck is before we really offer deep insights.

Comment: @xQbert updated my question, if i understand u correctly

Comment: Not quite: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain-output.html

Comment: Duplicate posting -- see your other post.

Comment: This question lacks a [mcve] (an explain plan) and thus can be put on hold for now.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming g.datetime is indexed, try this instead:

```
WHERE g.`datetime` BETWEEN 20150401 AND 20150430`
```

Using the MONTH function, or any other function, on the field data in the WHERE eliminates the benefits of any indexes you might have on those fields; this results in the query requiring a full scan of the values in the table.

Rearranging the order of JOINs will probably help as well:

```
SELECT s.id, s.player
   , SUM(case 
            when dg.winner = 1 AND dp.colour <= 5 then 1 
            when dg.winner = 2 AND dp.colour > 5 then 1 
            else 0
            end
     ) as totalwin
   , SUM(case 
            when dg.winner = 2 AND dp.colour <= 5 then 1 
            when dg.winner = 1 AND dp.colour > 5 then 1 
            else 0
            end
     ) as totallose
   , COUNT(dg.winner) as totalgames -- Not, sure of the nature of dg.`winner`, a SUM might be more appropriate here as well.
FROM games AS g 
INNER JOIN dotaplayers AS dp ON g.id = dp.gameid 
LEFT JOIN gameplayers AS gp ON gp.gameid = dp.gameid and dp.colour = gp.colour 
LEFT JOIN stats AS s ON s.player_lower = gp.name 
LEFT JOIN dotagames AS dg ON dg.gameid = dp.gameid 
LEFT JOIN bans as b ON b.name=gp.name
WHERE g.`datetime` BETWEEN 20150401000000 AND 20150430235959
GROUP by gp.name
ORDER BY totalwin DESC 
LIMIT 0,10
;
```

Another thing to note: Depending on the relationship between tables, some of the intermediate joins may result in effectively multiplying the resulting totals; this can be resolved by doing the sums in subqueries and joining those instead.

Comment: @PutraFajarHasanuddin Oh, if it is a datetime type, does adding the following help... `BETWEEN 20150401000000 AND 20150430235959`? Also, this will only help significantly if the field is indexed.

Comment: alot of time and effort going into fixing the where clause when order by with count on case statements could be the bottleneck.  maybe dg.winner and dp.colour are not indexed :P

Comment: @xQbert Wasn't that much work, just copied his original query and adjusted. Also, just caught his COUNTs as well; I don't think they work how he was hoping. I'll change them to SUMs.

Comment: thanks again, the result show is correct, but still same. Query took 8.0019 seconds

Comment: @PutraFajarHasanuddin You'll want to make sure (if possible) the fields you are joining with are indexed as well. 
dotaplayers and gameplayers should both have an index on (gameid, colour) in that order. Try commenting out different parts of the query (like `stats`) to see which is causing the worst of it. `bans` seems like it is completely unnecessary.

Comment: gameid, colour etc already indexed by the original writer, im sure the problem in WHERE datetime, bcoz i try just using original query and change just add WHERE datetime, then the query goes slow. The g.datetime already index too http://prntscr.com/7qe4mc

Comment: gameid, colour should be in an index in that specific order to gain significant benefits. Also, it is possible the original query ran fast because it's results were cached from a previous execution.